# How do I randomly choose a number in a smaller range than what my random number generator produces?

Tags: integers, uniform-distribution, random

My uniform random number generator can only produce integers in the range $0 \leq n \leq 255$. I need to use the output from this random number generator to generate another uniformly random integer in the range $0 \leq m \leq 209$. How can I do this?

Context: I need to randomly select an item from a list of 210 items using a random number supplied to me in the form of 8 random binary digits. I cannot change the range of the random number supplied to me.

EDIT: Some of the helpful comments suggest that I should use "rejection sampling". However, I would prefer a solution that has a guarantee on its maximum running time when implemented in a computer program.

Comment: You can keep generating random numbers from 0 to 255 until you get a value between 0 and 209, and take this value.

Comment: You can use rejection sampling for this , as the above comment says. You should try to prove that the above procedure works.

Comment: Alternative approach, if feasible is to multiply the generated number by the factor of $\frac{209}{255}$ and then round the product to the nearest integer.  The problem with this alternate approach is that (for example) $254$ will round down to $208$.  Therefore, your chance of having the computed random number be $209$ is $\frac{1}{256},~$ rather than $\frac{1}{210}$.  Personally, given that you insist on working with integers rather than real numbers, if you require that the random integers be **unbiased**, then I see no alternative to the already suggested rejection sampling.

Comment: If the priority between likelihood of avoiding a rejection and reducing bias is not so clear cut, there are compromises.  For example, the largest mutiple of $21$ that is $\leq 256$ is $252$.  Therefore, you could accept all numbers from $\{0,1,\cdots, 251\}$, and compute from the selected number an unbiased equivalence class $\pmod{21}$, and (simultaneously) a very slightly biased equivalence class $\pmod{10}$.  So, by introducing a small amount of bias, you have changed the *rejection interval* from $[210, 255]$ to $[252,255].$

Comment: Mathematically, you cannot produce an exact probability of $1/210$ using only a probability space whose elements have probability $1/2^n$ for some integer $n$, which is usually what you get from pseudorandom number generators on a computer. What most people do is to use a RNG that has a much larger probability space (range $0 \leq n \leq 2^{32}-1,$ typically) and divide it into $210$ almost-equal parts. You could do that too by running your RNG four times to build up a $32$-bit number.

Comment: You can also do an exact, "lazy" version of @DavidK's suggestion: interpret your random bits as the binary representation of a real number $x$ in $[0,1]$, and stop sampling when you have enough information to determine which one of the 210 equally-sized subintervals contains $x$.